# Powershell Function Switch

Tags: function, powershell, pipeline

I'm trying to create a quasi-logging function and pass the function parameter as a variable for possible output.

```bsh
Function Get-Function($continue) {
    if (!$error) {
        Write-Host "pass"
    } else {
        $continue
    }
}

Get-Function -continue $("$(write-host)success")
```

If there is an error it outputs `success` which is listed after the `-continue` flag.

But this version errors due to the pipeline:

```bsh
Get-Function -continue $("$(Write-Host)success") | Write-Host "this fails"
```

It creates an error after the pipeline.

Comment: I can't comprehend this post, but I'll just throw something out there until the smart people arrive. I don't know what `Get-function` does, but `Write-Host` can accept a piped value in its `-Object` parameter. That is the same parameter that accepts positional input. You can't combine the two, i.e. `"string" | write-host "string 2"` will error. However, `"string" | write-host` and `write-host "string"` both work.

Comment: Also, `$("$(write-host)success")` appears unnecessary when `$(write-host "success")` is enough unless that extra empty line is intentional.

Comment: I couldnt get anything to work properly without $("$(

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. `Make` is not a valid keyword in PowerShell, and I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Please [edit] your question and explain in more detail what you expect the function to do (example output usually helps). Also show the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to the question, but it's failing because you're trying to pipe information into a command which you already are giving the parameters. For example:

Works:

```
"Success" | Write-Host

Write-Host "Success"
```

Fails:

```
"Success" | write-host "Success"
```

If you change that line to just `Get-Function -continue "$(Write-Host)success" | Write-Host`, it will work but is pointless. You have `Write-Host` in your function, so there's really no point to write it again. Hope that helps!